# Should error codes in JSON be integers or strings?

Tags: design-patterns, programming-practices, api, json, error-messages

I'm designing a backend webservice, and when an error occurs I'm returning it as a JSON to the frontend. This JSON contains an error code, which the frontend maps to an localized string and shows that to the user.

Should my error codes be strings or integers?

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 9900,
    "message": "Invalid ID"
  }
}
```

OR

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "9900",
    "message": "Invalid ID"
  }
}
```

I'm thinking integers myself, but I'm just wondering if maybe returning fixed length error codes would be more correct, like if I atm have error codes like 9900, 9901, and in the future I wanna send the code 12, would it be correct to send them as `"9900"`, `"9901"`, and `"0012"`, vs  `9900`, `9901`, and `12`.

Comment: Any particular reason you're thinking of for returning a string or?

Comment: @MilanVelebit Just wondering if maybe returning fixed length error codes would be more correct, like if I atm have error codes like 9900, 9901, and in the future I wanna send the code 12, would it be correct to send them as `"9900"`, `"9901"`, and `"0012"`, vs  `9900`, `9901`, and `12`.

Comment: No, I was just wondering whether there was a special reason for returning a number as a string. If none, I'd personally just use a plain number.

Comment: Just want to note that the question is based on very flawed premises: neither is more or less "correct". There is no one true answer. There only is: fits my needs today? and fits my likely needs tomorrow? If you can tick both for all your options, toss a coin if you don't want to decide yourself.

Comment: @marstato 'neither is more or less "correct"'  I disagree.  Numbers are numbers and strings are strings.  Treating strings as if they are numbers is a mistake.

Comment: @JimmyJames but what are error codes? Doing comparisons on error codes seem already fishy to me; but any less-than or greater-than that you can do with numerical error codes can be the same with a starts_with and string error codes.

Comment: @marstato Right, error codes are ids.  They are not quantities.  You can't do math on them.  The only real advantage of using integer is storage and for JSON that's pretty much irrelevant.  Ultimately, even if you store them as integers, they should be treated like strings.

Comment: Why "9900", seems unhelpful either way. Would you consider "INVALID_ID"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would go with text.  It's OK to have a string where you only use numbers.  As a rule of thumb: you should not use integers for things that are not mathematical in nature.  That is, if you can do addition or multiplication on the values in a sensible way, then it's a number.  Otherwise it's an identifier and you should stick with text.  In practice you will probably be fine but using integer types to hold things that are not really numbers can end up being a problem.  A classic example is using an integer to store zip-codes i.e. US postal codes.

Comment: So what if the error string is "abcde"? Is that a valid error string or an error? (Errors in error reporting are usually fatal). Are "12" and "0012" the same or different errors? If they are the same, you can't just compare them as strings, you have to convert them to integers, so why not send them as integers in the first place?

Comment: @gnasher729 "Are "12" and "0012" the same or different errors?" Different.  Whatever system you are using, you should be consistent.  There's no reason to convert your error codes to integers for the same reason you shouldn't represent them as integers.  They don't represent quantities.  They are strings that may or may not contain only digits.

Answer (score 5):

I'd suggest to a static constant string to both be able to map to i18n and keep expressiveness.

Something like this is nice:

```
{
 error: 'invalid_id'
}
```

And you can even scope it to module to locate the origin of the error and avoid overlapping:

```
{
 error: 'auth.invalid_id'
}
```

Or, you could also add the http response code inside the object, but that's redundant with the response itself, but might be useful in some case you want to be independent of HTTP and maybe use other type of communication but still use the semantic of it.

```
{
 error: {
   key: 'auth.invalid_id',
   http_code: 401
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you need to do math on it? if errorCode>9000 etc
Do you need to pass it into anything that expects an integer?
Do you want an early error if you accidentally type an x in the code value?

If you answered no to all of these I can't see a reason why not to use strings.

As for [your comment about 0012 vs 12](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/395715/should-error-codes-in-json-be-integers-or-strings#comment871277_395715), that's a presentation issue. The backend shouldn't care which you do. But it does presume 9999 is your biggest error code.

Comment: You can still do greater than and less than on alphanumeric values.

Comment: @JimmyJames: 1, 10, 11, 12 ... 18, 19, 2, 20, 21...

Comment: @RobertHarvey '01', '02', '10', '11', '12' ... '19', '20', '21'

Comment: @JimmyJames: Well, yeah.  But you're making an assumption the OP didn't make (yet).

Comment: @RobertHarvey In the second comment on the question the OP mentions using code "0012" instead of 12.

Comment: @JimmyJames: The OP also asks if doing that is OK.  "Half-baked" comes to mind.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Treating error codes as integers is not robust.  It's an error.  Just like zipcodes, telephone numbers, or any other identifier, they don't represent quantities.  In fact, treating them as numbers only constrains you.  Once you decide you code class is x0, you are limited to 10 values in that class if you treat your code like it's a quantity.

Comment: @JimmyJames: I never said otherwise.

Comment: @RobertHarvey It's the kind of thinking that led a delivery person to leave a package for an xx9 address between two houses xx7 and x11 in my neighborhood.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I guess I misunderstood what you meany by 'half-baked'.  Sorry.

Comment: @JimmyJames: In any case, greater than and less than on a string is only meaningful if you're sorting them, and there are ways that can go wrong.  That's all I'm saying.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I have a counter example, actually.  [GICS codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Industry_Classification_Standard) are structured e.g. sector 'Energy' is "10" Industry Group 'Energy' is "1010" and  sector 'Materials' is "15" industry group 'Materials' is "1510" etc.  If you treat them like integers, your sorting is goofy.  But that's really kind of the point, what other reason are you comparing codes, other than to sort them or apply some sort of ordering?  What does it mean if my telephone number is larger than yours or vice-versa?

Comment: At the end of the day error codes need to do two things. 1. Be something to display to a user. 2. Be something that you can use to jmp to an error handler. Ints, strings, exception classes, NaNs, whatever you choose to express errors with you have to have a plan deal with both cases.

Answer (score 1):

Nobody has brought this up but numbers are usually better for i18n.  The client can decide what text to display.  In many cases the client will have to translate the text depending on the locale, so in most cases this is easily done on the client as there are mechanisms to handle internationalization.

@Bellon's answer also sends the text as well for troubleshooting purposes as someone who is not familiar with number codes can see what the error is.

Answer (score 0):

```
{
    "code": 9900,
    "message": "Invalid ID"
}
```

Should be the most appropriate. The standard for numbers requires not to have quotes.

https://www.json.org/

http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-404.pdf

Personally, I'd suggest to follow a pattern for code values similar to the one used by HTTP, so grouping categories of errors (not necessarily grouped by hundreds, but maybe by tens)

Comment: "The standard for numbers requires not to have quotes." -- Not sure I follow. `"9900"` is a valid JSON string. The question is if the value should be a number or a string, not what the JSON standard is about.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send integers, send them as integers. If you have an error code “abcde” then send strings. If “12” and “0012” are different error codes then send strings. But if you the receiver wants integers, send integers.

Comment: While technically this is true, it would be a horrible design, to have "0012" and "12" as two different error cases. It's pretty much guaranteed, that someone will confuse the two.

Comment: You’re absolutely right. So send integers.